# Is the Java virtual machine language agnostic?

Tags: java, language-agnostic, stack, forth

Is it safe to say that the Java virtual machine was 'originally' designed for the Java programming language, but now, other developers have been able to write programming languages that compile to Java bytecode like Scala, Jython and JRuby.

There are still 'object oriented' references in the Java bytecode like interfaces, methods, fields.  For example invokespecial is a call on a 'object' method.

It is not a pure stack virtual machine with pure a language agnostic instruction set.  For example, a pure FORTH implementation would only have stack operations.

The question, is the JVM language agnostic or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the sense that the JVM and java bytecode is turing-complete, any other turing-complete language can be transformed and compiled to java bytecode and run on the JVM. It may be horribly inefficient, but not impossible. As for the strictest possible definition of "agnostic", there is no such thing. At a hardware-level, all processors have a defined set of binary instructions they support so at some point, any language will have to be transformed to an assembly compatible with the hardware it's supposed to execute on.

EDIT:
The JVM was not developed in a vacuum, it was developed in conjunction with the JAVA programming language so it stands to reason that the Java language heavily influenced the design of the Java byte-code and the JVM. So in that sense, you could say that the JVM was designed with Java in mind. But it is also true that in the architecture, the JVM was consciously de-coupled from the Java language (through the intermediate bytecode format) so there are elements in the design that takes possible alternative languages into account.

Comment: I meant, is the JVM designed specifically for Java or not in that sense.

Comment: +1 Yes, they are all Turing complete, and at one level of efficiency or another, can be used to simulate the other.

Comment: @BerlinBrown The JVM was not developed in a vacuum, it was developed in conjunction with the JAVA programming language so it stands to reason that the Java language heavily influenced the design of the Java byte-code and the JVM. So in that sense, you could say that the JVM was designed with Java in mind. But it is also true that in the architecture, the JVM was consciously de-coupled from the Java language (through the intermediate bytecode format) so there are elements in the design that takes possible alternative languages into account.

Comment: Cool pap, that is a good response.   You might want to add that to your answer.

Answer (score 9):

The JVM is definitely not language-agnostic, and some languages can't be implemented efficiently on it. The JVM offers no memory addressing operations, for instance, so an implementation of a lower-level language like C would be horribly inefficient. But its set of primitives is capable of supporting many popular languages with features different from Java's, given a suitably smart compiler. The languages that can be implemented decently aren't necessarily just Java with syntactic sugar; but of course the more different you get from Java, the harder it is to implement the language

Comment: ... as long as those "popular languages" are semantically equivalent to Java...

Comment: I don't know all of the details, but they say that a fast haskell implementation for the JVM would be difficult.  Also, a stack machine wouldn't normally have memory addressing operations.  A register machine might.

Comment: @SK: In Clintonian fashion, I have to say that depends on your definition of "semantically equivalent." Java has only static typing; Ruby has "duck typing." Yet JRuby exists.

Comment: Ignoring the builtin OOP instructions some languages are better suited for a register based vm (parrot) instead of a stack based vm (jvm).

Comment: Java is still an imperative, object oriented language.  JRuby has a similar program flow.  Call a method with arguments on an object and repeat.  There may difficultly in implementing something like Haskell or Erlang on top of the Java virtual machine without hacks.

Comment: @Ernest, it is a minor difference, and still JRuby compiler is really complicated. JVM won't allow you to compile *efficiently* (and Ruby was never designed for efficiency anyway) any language which is significantly different from Java. Two major issues are: a lack of explicit tail calls and a ridiculous method size limit.

Comment: If you want, you can write an interpreter for the other language in Java.  It's how they managed to get many languages in the JVM, especially when the language makes assumptions about the machine that doesn't hold for the JVM.  Since all Turing-complete languages have (provably) equal (expressive) power, some Rube Goldberg solution should exist for every Turing-complete language to simulate another Turing-complete lanugage's operations.

Comment: @Berlin, yes, in order to implement STG (i.e., Haskell) efficiently you'd need at least unions - which is practically impossible in JVM.

Comment: SK-logic, you seem to imply that an efficient Haskell implementation must be implemented as a STG. How comes?

Comment: @Ingo, mind naming more efficient approaches which won't require low level memory tricks?

Comment: SK - more efficient than *what* (given that a STG can't be implemented in Java/bytecode (a point I don't want to discuss here))?  Anyway, you may want to try if Frege (see my profile for link) is efficient enough.

Comment: I am unclear on why this discussion is going in this direction, as my original statement was that the JVM is *not* language-agnostic, and some languages can't be implemented efficiently on it. My response to @SK was that the languages that *can* be implemented decently aren't necessarily just Java with syntactic sugar; but of course the whole point is that yeah, the more different you get from Java, the harder it is to implement the language.

Comment: @SK-logic, I can't see how "list" unions are a make-or-break point.  In my mind, I could easily solve the same problem in Java using LinkedHashMaps, with which I could quickly remove similar items in the second list using the hash table routines based on removeAll(...) and the join the two cleanly using addAll(...).  Now to build a GTC understanding machine might be nice, but it has little to do with solving the problem of porting the language, unless you intend to port GTC instead of haskell.

Comment: @Ernest, completely understood.  But most people don't know JVM bytecode, or the JVM machine model, so they think on language-level terms, in the wrong language.  For example, a language that lacks classes might be seen as "difficult" to port, when in reality other aspects (continuations, memory model, etc) are really the sticky parts.

Comment: @Ernest, I totally agree with your latest wording. Mind adjusting your answer?

Comment: @Ingo, thanks, I'll take a look. How does it perform against the current GHC with llvm backend?

Comment: Interesting question, I did not take the chance yet to try this out. But Haskell performance will be much better, I bet, because the Frege compiler does only a few optimizations yet. AFAICS, Haskell can compete with C++. Frege will never be faster than Java, after all, it's compiled to Java and there is some overhead for lazy evaluation.

Comment: @SK-logic: Why would the VM have to know or care about tail calls?  Couldn't the language compiler simply generate a loop?  As for a size limit, what would limit the ability of a language to subdivide a method into pieces?  It may be necessary for the language to add stack-trace-cleanup code at some strategic points, and cross-language execution could for that and other reasons be a little awkward, but I don't see how either of those things would limit what one could do in a JVM language.

Comment: @supercat, no, language compiler cannot make a loop if the tail call is a *virtual* call. And I gave an example when a huge method is absolutely essential - a large state machine, where transition between methods will bring an unacceptable overhead.

Comment: @SK-logic: That's a bit harder to handle; if interoperability with code in other languages weren't an issue, the compiler could split each method which tail-calls into a pair of methods; the second method, rather than performing the virtual a tail call itself, returns an object upon which the call should be performed (or `null` if none); the first method then calls the second repeatedly until it returns `null`.  Not sure how languages could inter-operate without an agreed-upon convention for how the methods should be split, though.

Comment: @supercat, it is not "a bit harder to handle", it is impossible to handle *efficiently*. A trampoline you're describing is extremely inefficient. And it should have been trivial to handle it on a JVM level, just as .NET did.

Comment: @SK-logic: The times I've used such things, the overhead was slight compared with everything else that needed to be done, but I can imagine that in cases where little else would need to be done the overhead could be noticeable (though I wouldn't think it would be horrible).  Still, I can see value in a tail-call feature even from a language perspective: an explicit `tail return` statement could be handy, and if the VM supported it could be added without affecting any presently-legal constructs.

Comment: @SK-logic: BTW, how efficient or inefficient is the JVM at using "thread-static" variables?  Some of the more efficient ways I've done trampolining in single-thread code have used global variables, but in a multi-threaded world, per-thread static variables would likely be required instead.  If thread-static variables are efficient, I would think trampolining could be as well.  If they're doggy, then trampolining would be likewise.

Comment: @supercat, call frame sanitising adds only about 20% overhead to the .NET tail calls implementation. I suspect, even the most efficient trampoline will be much, much slower, although I admit I never tried benchmarking this directly in JVM.

Comment: The more I think about it, the less certain I am that a compiler would likely be able to perform efficient folding in the general case.  Nonetheless, it would be interesting to know how the efficiency of `while(action != null) action=action.invoke();` would compare with normal recursion (assuming the stack didn't bomb!) if one either uses thread-static action objects or, if thread-static variables are too slow, adds an extra parameter to each function call to carry around a reference to an object which holds all the stuff that would be thread-static.

Answer (score 4):

The JVM is not language-agnostic; however, it's language is JVM bytecode.  Consider that the assembly of the virtual machine and then you'll have a good idea of what the JVM runs.  JVM bytecode was selected to facilitate running Java programs, but like any "complete enough" assembly, it can be used for many other things.  The key is what's being done in the compilation process.

Other language barriers include the design that the JVM is a stack based machine, which means explicit addresses are nonsense to the JVM in the bytecode layer.  There's no "load" or "store" operations; however, that doesn't stop people who want to implement languages that do addressing on the JVM.  It just makes it harder for those who want to do addressing.

To do addressing on the JVM, you basically write a simulator; where you have an object containing the "address to object handle" lookup table.  This allows you to do rudimentary addressing via simulation on a virtual machine that lacks addressing.  It's not always pretty, and the quality of the simulation is only typically extended to the use cases that the simulated language would permit.

Yes, you do lose a bit of performance doing Address(the object) to Map(of object to Java heap reference) to (internally in the JVM) java heap reference to physical memory address.  But that's what has to be done to keep the platform agnostic.  If you had direct memory access, you would eventually be pushed into coding for different hardware platforms instead of coding for the virtual machine.  Well, at least you would be pushed into platform specific code much earlier than occurs these days.

Comment: Depending upon what one is doing with "addresses", one could, I would think, just use a few `int[]` to hold everything of interest.  In some cases, even when writing Java, using an int[] to a collection structured data may be more efficient than using an array of objects.  For example, a program which will need many immutable lists of integers, many of which could be short, could store all the lists within a single `int[]`, each preceded by length, and pass around indices into the array rather than references to array objects.

Comment: Exactly what kind of portable across platform int are you talking about?  Exactly what kind of int can hold addresses?  Sure it works on some platforms, sometimes, under certain operating systems; but, outside of one or two popular combinations, it fails for everything else.

Comment: If one were trying to write an emulator for a classic 512K Macintosh in Java, one could use an `short[] mem = new short[262144]` to hold the contents of its memory; one would store `value16` to `addr` by `if (addr & 1) throw someException; else mem[addr>>1]=value16;`  A byte store would be `if (addr & 1) mem[addr>>=1] = (mem[addr>>1] & 0x00FF) | (value8 << 8); else (mem[addr>>=1] = (mem[addr>>1] & 0xFF00) | (value8);`.  Not exactly elegant, but adequate for many purposes.  If one can use word-based rather than byte-based addresses, the LSB handling may be avoided.

Comment: And if one were to write a JVM on a 64 bit memory addressing model that supported 32 bit ints?  And what about all the other systems?  The idea that the best plan of action is to throw away C's type checking in favor of int packing of addresses is borderline rediculous.  What's wrong with using a void* (or better yet a struct*), where they size might not be known, but you don't have to work against the type system?

Comment: A C compiler for the JVM could produce code which would store a reference to one or more arrays in a `static` variable and then use those arrays to hold everything whose address is ever taken.  The compiler would translate code which uses things like structs into JVM code that generates suitable array accesses for things whose address isn't taken (a struct whose address is never taken could simply be regarded as a bunch of independent variables).  Since the JVM has no concept of non-primitive value types, any sort of array-of-struct behavior will have to be emulated anyway.

Comment: To be sure, pointers allow one to do something else one can't do with heap-only references, which is to construct a reference to an ephemeral variable.  The .NET framework includes an ephemeral-pointer type which can prevent the propagation of a pointer outside the scope where it is created, but Java lacks any ephemeral types.  I would consider the lack of ephemeral reference type to be a weakness more fundamental than the lack of pointer support.

Comment: You do realize that the JVM is written in C?  All of your C# / Java examples don't play a role how the JVM internally works, and the suggestion that one __in C__  should favor int arrays to hold memory addresses is __very bad practice__ in __C__, no matter what other kinds of features other languages have.

Comment: One of the fundamental design goals of Java is to ensure that there is absolutely no possibility whatsoever of an reference to one object becoming a reference to something else.  In C, if code receives a pointer from `calloc` and later calls `free` on it without destroying all copies of the pointer, it's possible that those copies of the pointer might arbitrarily turn into seemingly-valid pointers to some other random object.  In order for Java to work effectively as a "sandbox", it must ensure that can't happen.  Running C code in a sandbox would require...

Comment: ...that there not be any sequence of events via which the code could induce unconstrained Undefined Behavior.  Note that I'm not suggesting that the person writing the code in C would write it to use arrays rather than other types; I'm suggesting that the *bytecode produced by the C compiler* for code that used C data types would achieve the indicated behaviors using a sequence of array operations.  Such a thing could allow C code to be run while ensuring that it was prevented from doing anything that could crash the host machine.

Comment: @supercat I think you are encountering some difficulty in separating these different concepts: Java as a Language, The Java runtime environment (JVM bytecode and execution), and the Java Virtual Machine.  The JVM is implemented in C, and it doesn't expose features of the C language to the Java language or it's runtime environment.  As such, any suggestion of int packing addresses would impact the JVM internals but not Java or the Runtime Enviornment (barring a bug that crashes the JVM or makes it operate outside of spec).  Why int pack?  It's bad C.  Who cares if it's bad C for a JVM or for X.

Comment: I was suggesting how one would write a C compiler which would could take the source code for a program written in portable C and produce a bytecode file whose behavior on the JVM would match that of running the portable C program on an ANSI-compliant compiler.  Note that in C it's possible to do use pointers in ways which are 100% guaranteed to be portable and yet could not be statically verified never to invoke Undefined Behavior.  Only by using arrays as a backing store could the compiler match the standards-mandated behavior of the C code.

Comment: As for "why int pack", if a compiler is trying to produce a JVM-compatible equivalent of C code which uses a `char*` to modify parts of an `int`, and the C compiler defines CHAR_MAX as 255 and UINT_MAX as 4294967295, what alternatives are there to either using multiple elements of a `byte[]` to store each C `int`, or using each element of an `int[]` to hold multiple C `char`?  I would expect that if the C implementation mandates that all int pointers be longword-aligned, int-packing would be faster.

Comment: Looking back through the comments, I think my original point was that trying to map addresses to object handles would in many cases be excessively complicated; given that C mandates that any data type, including pointers, can be decomposed into a sequence of `char` values and later reconstructed from that sequence, I don't know that trying to be more sophisticated is apt to be especially helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the builtin OOP instructions some languages are better suited for a register based VM (like parrot) instead of a stack based VM (like JVM).

This paper covers the issue nicely: http://db.usenix.org/events/vee05/full_papers/p153-yunhe.pdf